# how to get vscode to resolve java files in different directories

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode and RedHat Language Support for Java plugins.
I have some self-written java code which I have placed in a standard location (src/main/java) and there are also some java files which were generated for me -- so they reside in src/generated/main/... location.

All of the above compiles/builds and runs when using command line gradle commands.

What doesnt work is the IDe stuff -- it seems that when importing/referencing generated classes in my self-written classes, its all  "red" -- "import cannot be resolved".  But like I said, its purely an IDE issue -- the code actually build and runs.

Any idea how to make it more IDE friendly?
Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once and the solution for me was to clean the project.

If you have plugin version `0.33.0` or higher, open command palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and type `java clean`. If the problem continues try to restart VS Code.